# How to float boxes this way?

Tags: jquery, css

How can I achieve [this effect](http://i45.tinypic.com/2krdb6.jpg) with CSS and/or jQuery?

[image]

I would post the code I've written so far but it's useless...

Comment: Please do post the code.  This is a programming Q&A site, and we can't help you with your code if we can't see it.  As it stands, your question isn't a good fit here.  With code, it might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to achieve this. You can't achieve this with CSS alone.

Comment: the link to Isotope seems to be broken

Comment: @IonutHulub: I think their website was down, but it's working for me now.